# Why is one set countable while the other uncountable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

This is an example from Chapter 1 of David Williams book - Probability with Martingales.

Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu) = ([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),Leb)$. Let $V=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]=\{v_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Let $\epsilon(k) \downarrow 0$. We have 
$$V\subseteq G_k = \bigcup_n \{ v_n-\epsilon(k)2^{-n},v_n+\epsilon(k)2^{-n} \}\cap S = \bigcup_n I_{n,k}$$
He claims $H=\bigcap\limits_k \bigcup\limits_n I_{n,k}$ is an uncountable set (which has a measure 0), while $\bigcup\limits_n \bigcap\limits_k  I_{n,k}=V$, the set we started with. I understand the latter, but I don't see why the former isn't $V$ as well.

a) What is an example of a point that is in $H$ but not in $V$, and b) why is $H$ uncountable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the first part of the question and provide one explicit example of a point in $H\setminus V$:

Let $\epsilon(k)=2^{-k}$ and, just as a technical trick to satisfy the requirement that $V=\{v_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, let $v_n$ be defined such that for even indices, $$v_{2t}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^t 2^{-j^2}$$
The odd ones will cover whatever remains of $V$. Now, consider the number $$a=\lim_{t\to\infty} v_{2t}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j^2}$$
For any fixed $k$, we can set $n=2k$ and find out that $a\in I_{n,k}$:
$$|a-v_n| = \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty 2^{-j^2} < 2\cdot 2^{-(k+1)^2} \leq 2^{-n}2^{-k}=2^{-n}\epsilon(k)$$

Since $G_k=\bigcup\limits_{n} I_{n,k}$, we can conclude that $a\in G_k$ and thus also 
$a\in \bigcap\limits_k G_k=H$. However, the number $a$ is irrational and cannot belong to $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for each fixed $k$, $H_k = [0,1]\setminus G_k$ is a nowhere dense set. So $\bigcup_k H_k$ is also nowhere dense by the Baire Category theorem. Thus $H = [0,1]\setminus \bigcup H_k$ contains an open intervals and is uncountable. The reason is that the closure of $\bigcup H_k$ will miss at least one element $v \in V$ (if not, then the closure of $\bigcup H_k$ will contain the whole interval $[0,1]$ and does not have empty interior). Then there is open neighborhood of $v$ in $H$.